# Reading or Writing Excel (xlsx) file from java

Tags: java, excel, xlsx

What is the best api or library to read Excel (xlsx) files from java?

Comment: Best is not easy to answer. Please try Apache-POI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apache poi is a very good option.

Comment: thx :) it seems nice